# Reactor Netty IdleStateHandler as a keepalive mechanism breaks http2 connections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, netty, project-reactor, http2

I'm using Spring Webflux for sending Server Sent Events over HTTP:

```
 @GetMapping("/dummysse")
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<UpdateResponse>> handleSse(@RequestParam(required = false) String code) {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .map(e -> wrapIntoSse(new Update(code, e)));
    }


    private ServerSentEvent<UpdateResponse> wrapIntoSse(Update Update) {
        return ServerSentEvent.builder(new UpdateResponse(Update.getCode()))
                .event("update-event")
                .build();
    }
}
```

I also have a Netty's IdleStateHandler to keep alive long-lived SSE connections:

```
public final class NettyKeepAliveCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

    private final SseKeepAliveConfiguration configuration;
    private static final String DATA = "\n";

    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addServerCustomizers(builder -> builder.doOnChannelInit((connectionObserver, channel, remoteAddress) -> {
            final ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
            pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(configuration.getReaderIdle(),
                    configuration.getWriterIdle(),
                    configuration.getAllIdle()));
            pipeline.addLast(new IdleHandler());
        }));
    }


    private static final class IdleHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

        @Override
        public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
            if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent e) {
                if (e.state() == IdleState.WRITER_IDLE) {
                    final ByteBuf byteBufMsg = ctx.alloc().buffer(DATA.length());
                    byteBufMsg.writeBytes(DATA.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    ctx.writeAndFlush(byteBufMsg);
                }
            }
            super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
        }
    }
}
```

I have an issue that appears only when HTTP2 is enabled:

1. Client connects to /dummysse and waits for updates.
2. A couple of updates arrive over SSE (optional).
3. Meanwhile IdleStateHandler does a couple of cycles, sending "\n" over the stream.
4. After a few IdleStateHandler cycles the next update over SSE breaks the connection, which is not expected and happens only when HTTP2 is enabled

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was close to the solution

```
@Override
public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
    factory.addServerCustomizers(builder ->
            builder.doOnConnection(connection -> {
                connection.addHandlerLast(new IdleStateHandler((int) configuration.getReaderIdle().getSeconds(),
                        (int) configuration.getWriterIdle().getSeconds(),
                        (int) configuration.getAllIdle().getSeconds()));
                connection.addHandlerLast(new IdleHandler());
            }));
}
```

Instead of adding handler to the channel pipeline, I should have added a last handler to the connection. Thanks to the reactor team on gitter for showing me my mistake.